# Error: userHelper could not be found in cakephp3.5.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to fix this issue

> Error: userHelper could not be found.

this is my `search.ctp` inside element which is called in `default.ctp`

```
<?php  echo $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'search']], array('type' => 'get'));  ?>  

<?php  echo $this->Form->input('username'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->button('Search', ['type' => 'submit']); ?>
```

Below is my search controller

```
public function search() {
   $value = $this->request->getData('username'); 
   $results = $this->Users->find('all', ['fields'=>[
        'Users.username',
        'Users.email',
        'Users.id',
        'Users.age',
        'Users.address',
        'Users.gender'
      ],
      'order' => 'Users.id ASC',
      'conditions' => array(' username LIKE' => "%".$value."%")
   ]);
   $this->set('user', $results);
   $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

search.ctp inside users

```
<?php
   use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry; 
   use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;
   use App\Controller\AppController;
?>
<?php foreach ($user as $users): ?>
<?php echo $this->users->username;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: the error is not in the code you provided. My guess is that in your view you typed something like `$this->user` but it is impossible to say if you don't post the row that generates the error

Comment: i already added the code bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the line inside loop? It shouldn't be.

```
$this->users->username;
```

I'm not so sure returning as a array or object in cakephp 3.

But, I'm sure that it should be like that,

```
$users->username;
```

or

```
$users['username'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much again bro

Comment: bro how to make this function 
<?php $options = ['username' => 'username', 'address' => 'address','email' => 'email']; 
   echo $this->Form->input($options , array(
    'options' => $options,
    'type' => 'select',
    
    'label' => 'Select to search')
   ); ?>     ... this is the error  transliterator_transliterate() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given [CORE\src\Utility\Text.php, line 1068]

Comment: **$this->Form->input($options** this is wrong. You need to pass string in first $options. But, $options is array now that you declared it on top. Try replace with string such as **userIfo** (e.g)

Comment: if i do that bro, only that string will be the search field input, i want the address or email or username to be the search field input

Comment: Your input filed is <select>. Not text.

Comment: in your suggestion it will make a field with select name="userIfo"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154286/discussion-between-kevin-kyaw-and-jerome).